# Distance between two data frames of unequal size

Tags: r, dataframe, distance

I have two data frames of unequal size:

```
>df1

    b  c  d
a   2  3  4

>df2

   g  h  i
e  1  1  5
f  0  4  3
```

I need to calculate distances between elements of these data frames, by subtracting values contained in `df1` from every row in `df2`, thus I want to get:

```
   c  d  e
a  1  2  1
b  2  1  1
```

Trying `>myfunc1 <- function(x1,x2){abs(x1 - x2)} myfunc1(df1, df2)` as well as `df3 <- abs(df2 - df1)` doesn't help because of unequal sizes.

Comment: Does `df1` really only have one row? If so, you can do `df2 - df1[rep(1, nrow(df2)), ]`. If not, I think you need to expand your example to have 2 rows in `df1` and show what your desired output is at that point.

Comment: `df1` does have only one row, but `df2 - df1[rep(1, nrow(df2)), ]` gives as result only one row, which is not exactly what I needed, but thank you anyway for attempt :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require(purrr)

map2_df(df1, df2, ~abs(.x - .y))
```

Or Gregor's method: `abs(df2 - df1[rep(1, nrow(df2)), ])`

From my limited test, `map2_df` appears to be faster

```
df1 <- fread( "
b  c  d
2  3  4
")

df2 <- fread("    
g  h  i
1  1  5
0  4  3
")

df1 <- rbindlist(replicate(10000, df1, simplify = F))
df2 <- rbindlist(replicate(10000, df2, simplify = F))

require(purrr)
f1 <- function(){
  map2_df(df1, df2, ~abs(.x - .y)) 
}
f2 <- function(){
  abs(df2 - df1[rep(1, nrow(df2)), ]) 
}

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(f1(), f2())

#Unit: microseconds
# expr      min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# f1()  727.385  891.4875 1268.775  956.923 1471.179 4651.075   100
# f2() 1737.025 2011.2815 2666.744 2218.666 2889.846 8572.715   100
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the case is always that there is one row in the first matrix then a base r apply method can be used:

```
t(apply(df2, 1, function(x) abs(x - df1[1,])))
```

Comment: If you're going to convert to matrices, use recycling instead of `apply`: `t(t(df2) - unlist(df1))`